# static_assert causing program to not compile even though the assert is in the header of a function template

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

I am having some trouble with template metaprogramming. I am trying to create a templated function that automatically adjusts an array based on an enum class, and I was attempting to do this using substitution failure is not an error. I seem to be setting ambiguous overloads, and it seems as if my substitution failure is not an error is not correctly working.

Here is the code:

```c++
namespace Interface{

enum class Interfaces { WIFI, MQTT, BT, SERIAL }; 

template<int lower, int upper, int val, typename rtype>
struct ibounded{ 
    static_assert(lower < val); 
    static_assert(upper > val); 
    using TYPE = rtype; 
};

char filename[3 + sizeof(Interface::Interfaces)] = {'I', 'F'}; 

template<int filenum_t, int pos> inline auto _init_filename() -> typename ibounded<0, 9, filenum_t, void>::TYPE {
    Interface::filename[pos] = static_cast<char>(filenum_t) % 10;  
}; 

template<int filenum_t, int pos> inline auto _init_filename() -> typename ibounded<10, 99, filenum_t, void>::TYPE {
    Interface::filename[pos] = static_cast<char>(filenum_t); 
    _init_filename<filenum_t / 10, pos + 1>(); 
};

template<Interface::Interfaces I> 
void _init_filename() {
    _init_filename<static_cast<int>(I), 2>(); 
}; 

template<Interface::Interfaces I> bool enabled(){
    Interface::filename[0] = 'I'; 
    Interface::filename[1] = 'F';  
    _init_filename<I>(); 
    return true; 
}


};


#include <iostream>

using namespace std; 

int main(){

Interface::enabled<Interface::Interfaces::SERIAL>(); 

cout << Interface::filename << endl; 

};
```

What I am trying to achieve is have an enum class and an array, and automatically get the number value of the enum type and place that at the end of the array using a templated function. So, if I had

`enabled<Interface::Interfaces::SERIAL>()`

I would want Interface::filename to become "IF3". Or, if the enum was larger than 10, have filename become "IF03".

The error that I am getting is

```
test.cpp: In instantiation of ‘struct Interface::ibounded<10, 99, 3, void>’:
test.cpp:29:46:   required by substitution of ‘template<int filenum_t, int pos> typename Interface::ibounded<10, 99, filenum_t, void>::TYPE Interface::_init_filename() [with int filenum_t = 3; int pos = 2]’
test.cpp:36:43:   required from ‘void Interface::_init_filename() [with Interface::Interfaces I = Interface::Interfaces::SERIAL]’
test.cpp:42:22:   required from ‘bool Interface::enabled() [with Interface::Interfaces I = Interface::Interfaces::SERIAL]’
test.cpp:56:51:   required from here
test.cpp:18:25: error: static assertion failed
   18 |     static_assert(lower < val);
      |                   ~~~~~~^~~~~
test.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void Interface::_init_filename() [with Interface::Interfaces I = Interface::Interfaces::SERIAL]’:
test.cpp:42:22:   required from ‘bool Interface::enabled() [with Interface::Interfaces I = Interface::Interfaces::SERIAL]’
test.cpp:56:51:   required from here
test.cpp:36:43: error: call of overloaded ‘_init_filename<3, 2>()’ is ambiguous
   36 |     _init_filename<static_cast<int>(I), 2>();
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
test.cpp:25:46: note: candidate: ‘typename Interface::ibounded<0, 9, filenum_t, void>::TYPE Interface::_init_filename() [with int filenum_t = 3; int pos = 2; typename Interface::ibounded<0, 9, filenum_t, void>::TYPE = void]’
   25 | template<int filenum_t, int pos> inline auto _init_filename() -> typename ibounded<0, 9, filenum_t, void>::TYPE {
      |                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.cpp:29:46: note: candidate: ‘typename Interface::ibounded<10, 99, filenum_t, void>::TYPE Interface::_init_filename() [with int filenum_t = 3; int pos = 2; typename Interface::ibounded<10, 99, filenum_t, void>::TYPE = void]’
   29 | template<int filenum_t, int pos> inline auto _init_filename() -> typename ibounded<10, 99, filenum_t, void>::TYPE {
      |
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it seems as if my substitution failure is not an error is not correctly working.

The rule is "Substitution Failure Is Not An Error". However, this only applies to the process of *finding* a type.

What's happening here is that finding a matching type actually succeeds, but it lands on a type that happens to have a failing `static_assert()`, which causes a compilation error.

There never was any substitution failure to consider as "not an error".

For your `ibounded` type to be used in SFINAE, it needs to not exist at all when the condition doesn't pass.

Since you are trying to wrap your head around this, I think it's worth going over what it would take for `ibounded` to work. However, there's a way easier way to do this in practice, see below for details.

**Manual SFINAE:** (for your curiosity)

```
// First declare ibounded without defining it
template<int lower, 
         int upper, 
         int val, 
         typename rtype, 
         typename pass=std::true_type>  // <---- magic sauce here
struct ibounded;


// Add a partial specialization for which the pass parameter will be set to true or false depending on the condition.
template<int lower, int upper, int val, typename rtype>
struct ibounded<lower, 
                upper, 
                val, 
                rtype, 
                std::integral_constant<bool, (lower < val && upper > val)>> {
  using TYPE = rtype; 
};
```

The key point here is having a default value for the `pass` parameter in the original declaration. Because of it, any attempt to use the `ibounded<a, b, c, T>` type is actually trying to use `ibounded<a, b, c, T, std::true_type>`.

Now, onto the partial specialization. It defines the following types:

- `ibounded<a, b, c, void, std::true_type>`, but only when `a < c < b`
- `ibounded<a, b, c, void, std::false_type>`, but only when `a >= c >= b`

There doesn't exist a definition of `ibounded<a, b, c, T, std::true_type>` for which `c` is not between `a` and `b`. All that's left to do is to make sure that you never manually set the value of the `pass` parameter, and `ibounded` is good to go as a SFINAE test.

**Easier way:**
`std::enable_if_t<bool, T>` is a type that exists as `T` if the bool is true, and does not exist otherwise. So you can just use:

```
template<int lower, int upper, int val, typename rtype>
using ibounded = std::enable_if_t<(lower < val && upper > val), rtype>;
```

It *becoming* `rtype` makes using it a lot nicer as well, since you don't have to lookup the type:

```
template<int filenum_t, int pos> inline auto _init_filename() -> ibounded<0, 9, filenum_t, void> {
```

Comment: As a little post-scriptum: If this feels to you like combining seemingly unrelated things to pull off a weird hack, as opposed to using something that was a planned feature of the language, then you are correct!

Comment: I am slightly confused with the partial specialization. I understand that we are using the std::integral_constant to create either a std::true_type or std::false type, but wouldn't the compiler technically be allowed to use either to instantiate the partial specialization, making TYPE exist?

Comment: @FranklinV, You would be right in isolation. However, because of the default value on the base template. The compiler only ever tries to use `std::true_type`. It never attempts to use `std::false_type`. So while the types with `std::false_type` technically *could* exist, they don't matter because the compiler never attempts to use them. (This is why I pointed out the defaulted `true_type` as being the magic sauce)

Comment: I think this is starting to make sense! Is the reason that the compiler never attempts to use std::false_type to instantiate the template specialization due to the fact that the compiler prefers default arguments over partial specialization? Also, is the order in which c++ attempts to instantiate templates with default arguments and template specialization well defined? I only ask this because I am not sure what mechanism causes the compiler to not consider the case of std::false_type with the partially specialized template.

Comment: @FranklinV Consider this: If the default was not there, then `ibounded<a, b, c, void>` would cause an error with "wrong number of template arguments (4, should be 5)". "Filling in the blanks" is something that the compiler doesn't do by itself. All the compiler does is look at what arguments are there, and then picks the narrowest specialization that matches.